# Change values at different indexes of an array in one go

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I have an array of 100 student_marks.Suppose after a certain index , say 9 I want to add to each to student a certain value say 2 to the initial value, i.e suppose initially i have

```
student_mark[0]=5
student_mark[1]=6...
.... 
....
student_mark[9]=2
student_mark[10]=5
....
....
student_mark[99]=8
```

Then after adding 2 according to my requirements after index 9 , I should get something like this

```
student_mark[0]=5
student_mark[1]=6...
.... 
....
student_mark[9]=2
student_mark[10]=7
....
....
student_mark[99]=10
```

Is there a method to do this in one go without iterating from index 10 to 100 adding 2 each time individually.

Comment: That's kind of the use case for `for` loops. It's around 3 lines of easily-readable code, and will be extremely fast since it's C. If there's a more obvious (or even not-so-obvious) way of doing it faster, the compiler will probably optimize the code to that method, so you can choose what's most readable for the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way.  What is wrong with the `for` loop you describe?

If this is really the bottleneck in your program, I am guessing you are calling this code repeatedly.  In which case, there is likely a better *algorithm* to achieve your real end-goal (which is unknown to us), but to accomplish the specific task you described in the original post (adding two to every element of an array), you aren't going to find a better solution than a C `for` loop.

Comment: I have to do this with much larger array and for many values, which in turn will slow down my program.

Comment: If you think about it, there just cannot be a way to make it faster.  The CPU has to go to each location in memory and change the data there no matter what.  Written in C, and compiled with any modern compiler, this will work almost as fast as is possible with a minimum of extra effort.  Many compilers will even vectorize it for you.

Comment: Yes,there is a limit on time.. and besides this there are other things that my program must do.

Comment: @AnoopKanyan But have you *tried* a loop and seen if it will take less time than what you have allocated for total program execution? There's no use throwing out the `for` loop without knowing whether it will actually work or not.

Comment: It takes more time... and so I must think of a better algorithm.

Comment: I have my suspicions that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/213583). Looping over elements in an array and performing basic arithmetic on them is very fast in C. It may be that (mostly reiterating Andrey's recent addition) you have a program design that has led you to this situation, and rather than trying to find something to iterate faster over these elements, you need to do some redesign on the program such that iterating (if you would still need it after the redesign) won't take up as much execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Not without using some [heavy duty vector stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD). If you need to ask about that then it's not for you. Just iterate it, it is extraordinarily fast in C on modern hardware.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i;
for (i = 10; i < 100; i++){
    student_mark[i] +=2;
}
```

Comment: _Is there a method to do this in one go without iterating from index 10 to 100 adding 2 each time individually._